# Why does setattr work differently for attributes and methods?

Tags: python

When I set an attribute, `getattr` result's `id` changes to value `id`.
When I set a method, `getattr` result `id` doesn't change.
Why?

```
class A (object):
    a = 1
a = 42
print id(getattr(A, 'a'))
print id(a)
setattr(A, 'a', a)
print id(getattr(A, 'a'))
# Got:
#   36159832
#   36160840
#   36160840

class B (object):
    def b(self):
        return 1
b = lambda self: 42
print id(getattr(B, 'b'))
print id(b)
setattr(B, 'b', b)
print id(getattr(B, 'b'))
# Got:
#   140512684858496
#   140512684127608
#   140512684858496
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is based on how methods work in python

note that

```
>>> B.b
<unbound method B.<lambda>>
```

Methods are actually built using [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)

Updating the "method", the descriptor isn't changing

Looking inside the descriptor we find the underlying function does

```
class B (object):
    def b(self):
        return 1
b = lambda self: 42
print id(getattr(B, 'b'))
print id(b)
setattr(B, 'b', b)
print id(getattr(B, 'b'))
print id(getattr(B, 'b').im_func)  # grab function from the descriptor


4424060752
4440057568
4424060752
4440057568   # here's our new lambda
```

You can also have a look at

```
B.__dict__['b']
```

before and after

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i was looking for.